# What is the dimension of Attenuation in the LC-EMI filter design formula?

Tags: filter, noise, low-pass, passive-filter, emi-filtering

the following formula is presented in the paper titled "[guideline for a simplified differential mode EMI filter design](https://www.pes-publications.ee.ethz.ch/uploads/tx_ethpublications/Abstract_IEEE_Transactions_Raggl.pdf)". This is the amount of attenuation, the LC filter with L and C values provides.

[image]

when I insert the values of a presented case the resultant Att_LC value is much higher than the desired Att_req presented in the following table. should I change the dimensions or what?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The computed attenuation \$Att_{LC}\$ is probably in linear units. That is, the input signal is 1878 times the output signal, or a gain of 0.532m. I much prefer working in gain rather than attenuation, then output signal = input signal * gain.

The \$Att_{req}\$ is given in dB, which is \$20log_{10}(att)\$.

1878 = 65.47 dB, exact when rounded to one decimal place.